# incorrect result for scipy.stats.hypergeom.pmf

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I'm having trouble understanding why `scipy.stats.hypergeom.pmf()` throws `nan` when according to it's [own documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html) it doesn't seem like it should.

Consider this code block:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
(M, n, N) = (1, 0, 1)
pmf = stats.hypergeom.pmf(np.array([0, 1]), M=M, n=n, N=N)
print pmf
```

The output is `[ nan  nan]`.

However, according to the documentation:

> The probability mass function is defined as:
>   `pmf(k, M, n, N) = choose(n, k) * choose(M - n, N - k) / choose(M, N)`

When I run that code using `scipy` I get correct, non-`nan` answers:

```
from scipy.misc import comb
(M, n, N) = (1, 0, 1)
k=np.array([0, 1])
pmfGood = comb(n, k) * comb(M - n, N - k) / comb(M, N)
print pmfGood

[ 1.  0.]
```

Here is some version info for the packages I'm using:

I'm using Scipy version 0.15.1; Numpy version 1.8.2; and Python 2.7.9 [Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)]

Is this a bug?  What am I not understanding about `scipy.stats.hypergeom.pmf()`??

Comment: This looks like a bug for this corner case, `_argcheck` requires that all arguments are strictly positive. `stats.hypergeom._pmf(np.array([0, 1]), M=M, n=n, N=N)`, which does not go through the valid argument checking, gives your expected answer. You should report it to the scipy issue tracker on github, so it can be fixed.

Comment: I was looking at the source code for the wrong scipy version. This is already fixed in scipy master.  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4402